# How to keep menu item on top of text area?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jinternalframe, jmenuitem

I'm using netbeans to write the GUI.
I have a menu bar with few menu items and the main window has a text area all over it.
when I press the menu item,I cant see it because the text area is on top (the menu item internal frame is behind the text area)how can I make the menu item internal frame to be on the top ?(the text area will be on the background)

thanks

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Are you using layouts? Usually, it simplifies the things...

Comment: See also this [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html).

Comment: are you sure that you didn't mixing AWT Componets with Swing JComponents, then is everyting possible, including your issue http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/ and http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what problem you are facing but it seems like you are looking for [JLayeredPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html)

Some useful links:

1. [How to use layered pane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)
2. [How to use Internal frames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify a Z-Value index higher for the JMenu , when [adding](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) it to its container component.